# HTML Checkbox uncheck calls onfocusout event during onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an HTML checkbox with `onfocusout` and `onclick` event
when I uncheck the checkbox the `onfocusout` event is triggered
when the `onclick` event is triggered.
I have added the `onfocusout` event when the user uses tab navigation for the checkbox.
Since both the `onclick` and `onfocusout` calls the same function when I uncheck the checkbox it calls the same function twice.

How can i avoid the `onfocusout` when the user clicks the checkbox ?

```js
function triggerCheckBox() {
  console.log('trigger checkbox got called');
}
```

```html
<input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" 
     onfocusout="triggerCheckBox()" 
     onclick="triggerCheckBox()" 
     value="Bike">
       
<label for="myCheckbox"> I have a bike</label>

<br>
```

Comment: It depends on whether you click on the checkbox itself or the label. I get two messages when clicking on the label, only one for the checkbox.

Comment: If i click the label it is showing two messages

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: I guess clicking on the label temporarily focuses the checkbox, then focuses the label.

Comment: `focusout` triggers when the focus leaves the checkbox. Checking the box also puts it into focus; after that, clicking anywhere other than the checkbox (whether the label or elsewhere in the doc) will correctly fire the `focusout` event.     I suspect the best solution here is to not attach the event handler to the `focusout` event; you should *not* be firing click handlers or making changes to form field values when the user is just tabbing through the document.

Comment: Why do you use the same function for `onclick` and `onfocusout`? The two events are not very similar.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 2 functions, you can use one function using `onchange()`
So, from

```
<input onfocusout="triggerCheckBox()" onclick="triggerCheckBox()" id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="Bike">
```

to

```
<input onchange="triggerCheckBox()" id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="Bike">
```

if you must use 2 functions, then you can use a `flag` that checks if the checkbox was clicked or not.
for example :

```
 <input onfocusout="triggerCheckBox()" onclick="setClickFlag()" id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="Bike">
```

```
    <script>
        let clickFlag = false;

        function setClickFlag() {
            clickFlag = true;
            triggerCheckBox();
        }

        function triggerCheckBox() {
            if (clickFlag) {
                console.log('trigger checkbox got called');
                clickFlag = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The OP's use case is for detecting keyboard navigation, not for detecting changes to the checkbox.

Comment: i see, i must have miss understood he's queries. @Barmar then, should i delete this comment ?

Comment: The suggestion to use different functions seems reasonable.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your opinion, then I'll keep at it is, other people might find useful with related different issues,